# MVC5 IISExpress and Subdomains dont work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, subdomain

I have done the following

1. Set IISExpress to run as admin
2. set the project settings as follow. [image]
3. Added the following to host file

   ```
     127.0.0.1 dev.test.com:9888 
     127.0.0.1 dev.test.com
   ```
4. added the following to IIS config settings

   ```
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9888:localhost" />
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9888:dev.test.com" />
   ```

After doing all this and it still doesnt work, pinging dev.test.com resolves to 127.0.0.1 but still get a page not found when i try to debug the app

**UPDATE**
I also tried just going to http://dev.test.com as well still no workie.
here is my route code, the code does not get hit

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.Add(new SubdomainRoute());

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index"
        });


    }
```

Comment: I think problem is not with domain binding. It something related to MVC Url scheme. Can put web.config file sample here.

Comment: this code worked, i formatted my computer and all of a sudden it doesnt work so i did all the steps that were suggested from all the posts i could find. so I dont think this is a code issue but a setting somewhere that I missed.